# Please help reviewing suggested edits!

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I'm trying to help this site by regularly [reviewing](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review) First Posts and Late Answers, but this has become somewhat complicated as of late. Most of the time I'd like to edit the post to fix some grammar or improve the formatting. However, as the edit queue is currently full (40 is the maximum size), I can't do that anymore. Now that I've learned that [I'm not the only user with this problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348447/295232), and increasing the edit queue doesn't really solve the problem, I'm trying another way with this Meta post. Please, if you have the reputation and some free time, spend some time and review some items; with only a few minutes per day (or even per week) you can already make a difference.

Comment: Thanks! 40 that's quite small for a queue size :-/

Comment: How often do you find this problem in [webapps.se]?

Comment: This was the first time I experienced here. Thanks for your reviews, BTW!

Answer (score 5):

The issue is now fixed thanks to the reviewers. I believe we should [increase the default edit queue size as currently it is only 40](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348445/178179) as it's not respectful toward the edit authors to discard their edits.