# I cannot suggest edits anymore — Requesting moderators and users with 2K rep to please help review suggested edits

Tags: support, review, editing, suggested-edits

I would like to ask moderators and [users with 2K rep](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) (who are not on [strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389811/162827)) to kindly [review suggested edits](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits). We have a [backlog](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review) of [suggested edits](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) in the review queue — 29 at the time of writing.

As per the Meta SE post, [Rate limit suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/162827):

> this limit is now active network-wide:
> […]
>
> - at-most **5 pending suggested edits** per editor on graduated sites

As a user with less than 2K rep who has already made 5 pending suggested edits, I cannot suggest edits anymore, which also prevents me from doing the "edit" action in the review queues. At the time of writing, my oldest pending suggested edit was made on 2023-06-13, which was almost a month ago.

I am now getting this error message: "You have too many pending edits. Further edits cannot be submitted until prior edits have been approved".

[image: screenshot of error message]

This issue might affect multiple users who want to contribute to the quality of the site. I appreciate all reviewers' efforts in clearing the review queue. Thank you.

Related meta posts:

- [Can someone take a look at my older pending edits. I have one pending since October 13](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4869/7584)
- [Please help reviewing suggested edits!](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4733/7584)

Comment: Related: [Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange Moderators Strike](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5055/88163)

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed a few edits, that should be working now. Relevant feature request on Meta.SE: [Increase the default edit queue size (currently it is only 40)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348445/178179). The issue predates the ongoing strike.